# How do I put a loading icon while I am waiting for a XMLHttpRequest to fetch from the API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, cloudinary

I am currently working on a sign up page, and whenever a user adds a profile picture, it usually takes a while for the photo to appear (1 - 3 seconds), whilst this is loading I want to put a loading icon to indicate to the user that their image is taking some time to upload (calling to Cloudinary for image url). I have tried implemented myself but to no avail.

Here is my code in question:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { VectorIllustration } from "./VectorIllustration";
import { Avatar, Text, Loading } from '@nextui-org/react'
import { Button, IconButton, InputAdornment, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import '../../style-sheets/CreateYourProfile.css'
import { createUsers } from "../../reducers/usersReducer";
import AddAPhotoIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddAPhoto';
import AvatarPicture from '../../images/AvatarPicture.png'
import DescriptionIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Description';
import Select from 'react-select';
import makeAnimated from 'react-select/animated';
import userInformation from "../../services/userInformation";
import { useState } from "react";

const CreateYourProfile = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const state = useSelector(state => state)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();
  console.log(state)

  const handleImageSubmit = async (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', e.target.files[0]);
    formData.append('upload_preset', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_PRESET)
    formData.append('api_key', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_APIKEY)
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('POST', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_URL, false)
    xhr.send(formData);
    const imageResponse = await JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    setLoading(true)
    dispatch(createUsers(imageResponse.secure_url, 'profileImageURL'))
  }

  const handlePostUserToServer = async () => {
    const response = await userInformation.newUser(state.users)
    console.log(response)
  }

  const listOfAddictions = [{value: 'Alcohol', label: 'Alcohol'}, {value: 'Lust (Porn, sex, etc.)', label: 'Lust (Porn, sex, etc.)'}, {value:'Gambling', label: 'Gambling'}, {value: 'Food', label: 'Food'}, {value: 'Drugs', label: 'Drugs'}, {value: 'Nicotine', label: 'Nicotine'}, {value: 'Work', label: 'Work'}, {value: 'Pills', label: 'Pills'},
{value: 'Cocaine', label: 'Cocaine'}, {value: 'Crystal Meth', label: 'Crystal Meth'}, {value: 'Emotions', label: 'Emotions'}, {value: 'Marijuana', label: 'Marijuana'}, {value: 'Narcotics', label: 'Narcotics'}]

  const listOfGroups = [{value: 'Alcoholics Anonymous', label: 'Alcoholics Anonymous'}, {value: 'Cocaine Anonymous', label: 'Cocaine Anonymous'}, {value: 'Crystal Meth Anonymous', label: 'Crystal Meth Anonymous'}, {value: 'Emotions Anonymous', label: 'Emotions Anonymous' },{value: 'Eating Disorder Anonymous', label: 'Eating Disorder Anonymous'}, {value: 'Food Addicts in Recovery Anonymous', label: 'Food Addicts in Recovery Anonymous'},
 {value: 'Food Addicts Anonymous', label: 'Food Addicts Anonymous'}, {value: 'Gamblers Anonymous', label: 'Gamblers Anonymous'}, {value: 'Heroin Anonymous', label: 'Heroin Anonymous'}, {value: 'Love Addicts Anonymous', label: 'Love Addicts Anonymous'}, {value: 'Marijuana Anonymous', label: 'Marijuana Anonymous'}, {value: 'Narcotics Anonymous', label: 'Narcotics Anonymous'}, {value: 'Neurotics Anonymous', label: 'Neurotics Anonymous'}, {value: 'Nicotine Anonymous', label: 'Nicotine Anonymous'},
 {value: 'Overeaters Anonymous', label: 'Overeaters Anonymous'}, {value: 'Pills Anonymous', label: 'Pills Anonymous'}, {value: 'Racists Anonymous', label: 'Racists Anonymous'}, {value: 'Sexaholics Anonymous', label: 'Sexaholics Anonymous'}, {value: 'Sex Addicts Anonymous', label: 'Sex Addicts Anonymous'}, {value: 'Sexual Compulsives Anonymous', label: 'Sexual Compulsives Anonymous'}, {value: 'Sex and Love Addicts Anonymous', label: 'Sex and Love Addicts Anonymous'}, {value: 'Sexual Recovery Anonymous', label: 'Sexual Recovery Anonymous'},
 {value: 'Workaholics Anonymous', label: 'Workaholics Anonymous'}, {value: 'Racists Anonymous', label: 'Racists Anonymous'}]

  return (
    <div className="create-profile-page-container">
      <VectorIllustration />
      <div className="create-profile-form-container">   
          <input
            accept="image/*"
            id="contained-button-file"
            type="file"
            hidden
            aria-disabled={true}
            onChange={handleImageSubmit}
          />
        <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
          <IconButton style={{left: '40%', top: '10%'}} component='span'>
            {state.users.profileImageURL ? <Avatar src={state.users.profileImageURL} text={state.users.name} style={{width: '132px', height: '132px'}}/> : loading ? <Loading style={{width: '132px', height: '132px'}}/> : <Avatar src={AvatarPicture} text={state.users.name} style={{width: '132px', height: '132px'}}/>}
          </IconButton>
          <Button component='span' startIcon={<AddAPhotoIcon />} size='medium' style={{position: 'absolute', left: '35%', top: '25%'}}>Upload Profile Picture</Button>
        </label>
        <TextField multiline rows={5} label='Briefly Describe Yourself' style={{position: 'absolute', top: '35%', left: '32%', width: '300px', backgroundColor: 'white'}} inputProps={{
          maxLength: 250
        }} InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment>
              <DescriptionIcon color="primary"/>
            </InputAdornment>
          )
        }}  onChange={(e) => {
          dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'biography'))
        }}/>
        <Text style={{position: 'absolute', top: '54.5%', left: '31%', fontFamily: 'cursive'}} b size={24}>What do you struggle with?</Text>
        <Select
          closeMenuOnScroll={false}
          components={animatedComponents}
          defaultValue=''
          isMulti
          options={listOfAddictions}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          className='addiction-selector'
          onChange={(e) => {
            dispatch(createUsers(e.map(addiction => addiction?.value), 'addictions'))}}
        />
        <Text style={{position: 'absolute', top: '67%', left: '24%', fontFamily: 'cursive'}} b size={24}>Do you belong to any of these groups?</Text>
        <Select
          closeMenuOnScroll={false}
          components={animatedComponents}
          defaultValue=''
          isMulti
          options={listOfGroups}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          className='group-selector'
          onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e.map(group => group?.value), 'groups'))}
        />
        <Button className="submit-button" sx={{ position: 'absolute', color: 'white', top: '90%' }} type='submit' onClick={handlePostUserToServer}>Submit</Button>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CreateYourProfile;
```

I am using NextUI's Loading component for the icon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of off, when the submit is click you had set loading to true, that's good. After that you need to show the loading component by stating that only show if loading state is true, thus with the { Loading &&  }, after it completes, set it to false.

```js
<div className="create-profile-page-container">
      <VectorIllustration />
      {Loading && <YourNextUILoadingSpinner/> }
      <div className="create-profile-form-container">   
          <input
            accept="image/*"
            id="contained-button-file"
            type="file"
            hidden
            aria-disabled={true}
            onChange={handleImageSubmit}
          />
        <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
          <IconButton style={{left: '40%', top: '10%'}} component='span'>
            {state.users.profileImageURL ? <Avatar src={state.users.profileImageURL} text={state.users.name} style={{width: '132px', height: '132px'}}/> : loading ? <Loading style={{width: '132px', height: '132px'}}/> : <Avatar src={AvatarPicture} text={state.users.name} style={{width: '132px', height: '132px'}}/>}
          </IconButton>
          <Button component='span' startIcon={<AddAPhotoIcon />} size='medium' style={{position: 'absolute', left: '35%', top: '25%'}}>Upload Profile Picture</Button>
        </label>
        <TextField multiline rows={5} label='Briefly Describe Yourself' style={{position: 'absolute', top: '35%', left: '32%', width: '300px', backgroundColor: 'white'}} inputProps={{
          maxLength: 250
        }} InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment>
              <DescriptionIcon color="primary"/>
            </InputAdornment>
          )
        }}  onChange={(e) => {
          dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'biography'))
        }}/>
        <Text style={{position: 'absolute', top: '54.5%', left: '31%', fontFamily: 'cursive'}} b size={24}>What do you struggle with?</Text>
        <Select
          closeMenuOnScroll={false}
          components={animatedComponents}
          defaultValue=''
          isMulti
          options={listOfAddictions}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          className='addiction-selector'
          onChange={(e) => {
            dispatch(createUsers(e.map(addiction => addiction?.value), 'addictions'))}}
        />
        <Text style={{position: 'absolute', top: '67%', left: '24%', fontFamily: 'cursive'}} b size={24}>Do you belong to any of these groups?</Text>
        <Select
          closeMenuOnScroll={false}
          components={animatedComponents}
          defaultValue=''
          isMulti
          options={listOfGroups}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          className='group-selector'
          onChange={(e) => dispatch(createUsers(e.map(group => group?.value), 'groups'))}
        />
        <Button className="submit-button" sx={{ position: 'absolute', color: 'white', top: '90%' }} type='submit' onClick={handlePostUserToServer}>Submit</Button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

One other way is use a set timeout for 3 second and than set to false

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  setLoading(false)
  console.log("Delayed for 3 second.");
}, "3000")
```